# How to align xlabels and ylabels in subplot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, alignment

I have the following code:

```
  mean_h =[11.9877,13.3937,16.1717];
   std_h = [12.5379,10.2732,10.8000];
    subplot(2,1,1)
   hold on
    h = bar(1:3,mean_h,0.2);
   errorbar(1:3,mean_h,std_h,'s','MarkerSize',10,...
   'MarkerEdgeColor','red','MarkerFaceColor','red');
   name = {'4 mics','9 mics','24 mics'};
    set(gca,'XTick',[1 2 3],'XTickLabel',{'4 mics','9 mics','24 mics'});
   set(gca,'fontsize', 21);

  legend({'mean_{hor}', 'std_{hor}'});
  grid on
  xlabel(' 3 different subsets of horizontal microphone pair combinations of 
   microphone array 3');
   ylabel('Mean/stds rmse`s [°]');



 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %%% Mean and standard devaiation for vertical rmse's of microphone array 3
  mean_v =[7.3022,11.3737,16.2675];
 std_v =[6.2369,9.9813,10.3599];

subplot(2,1,2)
hold on
h = bar(1:3,mean_v,0.2);
errorbar(1:3,mean_v,std_v,'s','MarkerSize',10,...
'MarkerEdgeColor','red','MarkerFaceColor','red');
name = {'4 mics','9 mics','24 mics'};
set(gca,'XTick',[1 2 3],'XTickLabel',{'4 mics','9 mics','24 mics'});
set(gca,'fontsize', 21);
 legend({'mean_{ver}', 'std_{ver}'});

  grid on
  xlabel('3 different subsets of vertical microphone pair combinations of 
  microphone array 3');
  ylabel('Mean/stds rmse`s [°]');
```

Now when i plot these two subplots i am facing an alignment problem in xlabels and ylabels . They are not aligned. Can anybody help me how can i fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would clarify what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't align if the graphs are different. In your case the numbers are different.

You can either do it by hand or use a `text(my_x, my_y,'mylabel')` and set it up properly. I wrote an example below.

```
a=1:10;
b=a.^2;

subplot(4,1,1)
plot(a,b)
ylabel(' long text')

subplot(4,1,2)
plot(a,a)
ylabel('long even long text')

subplot(4,1,3)
hold
plot(a,b)
text(0,50,'long text','HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle', ...
'FontSize',12,'Rotation',90)

subplot(4,1,4)
hold
plot(a,a)
text(0,5,'long even long text','HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle', ...
'FontSize',12,'Rotation',90)
```

giving the graph below
[image: Graphs]

Notice the last two are aligned, but it was necessary to input the coordinates by hand as i did.
As a tip, you often ca use your data and move it by a fixed percentage (e.g., the minimum -10% graph total length), making it possible to 'automate' your script.

Another way is to use the [`Position`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html) property of the ylabel. But this is similar to the method described above. To do so use

```
t=ylabel('long text')
t = 
  Text ( long text) with properties:

                 String: ' long text'
               FontSize: 11
             FontWeight: 'normal'
               FontName: 'Helvetica'
                  Color: [0.15 0.15 0.15]
    HorizontalAlignment: 'center'
               Position: [0.3333 50 -1]
    %other things here too

%overwrite the property
% Here you have to put [X_position Y_position Z_position]
t.Position= [0.2 50 -1];
```

For that to work, every x/ylabel need its own name, or same name, but update the position before you call the command again.

Comment: I have one question: I have adjusted the parameters in text command on my own but still the label of y axis is mixing with the y-axis values . How it can be solved?? any idea

Comment: How to adjust label at y axis more towards left?

Comment: @AhmadBilal This depends on many graphical properties, as for instance, the graph sizes and the window size. Not a simple answer without a figure from your plot. Left and right depend on the values you will provide, play around with the numbers and see the behavior. It is a good exercise to have better plots in the future.

Comment: I am playing in the text command by trying different numbers but i am not getting the required answer